# Does SolrJ support the MoreLikeThisHandler?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Does any version of SolrJ (the Solr client for java) support MoreLikeThisHandler queries?

I am referring to the /mlt handler and not the /select handler, e.g. :

```
http://someserver:8080/myindex/mlt?fq=PrivacyLevel:0&q=id:62db612065d549b49892a855f85e2aaf&start=0&rows=5&mlt.minwl=3&mlt.mindf=1&mlt.mintf=1&mlt.fl=Name
```

For reference here is the MoreLikeThisHandler doc: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler

Thank you!

Comment: Any update on this so far?

Answer (score 1):

May want to try out the patch @ [SOLR-1085](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1085)

Comment: That is interesting. Thanks! Also there is a setRequestHandler method in the SolrQuery in Solr 4.0 that might be another answer. Probably passing "mlt" would replace the default "select". If I have a chance to test it I'll write up the results here.